# Why is the Typescript type checker upset about this unspecified type?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

I have a react component whose props

- need to be serialized / stored, **and**
- contain a function

My storage utility doesn't like storing functions, and I don't need the functions stored. So I wrote a function that returns a copy of the props object without the function component:

```
/**
 * Removes functions from the components props, so that the props can be pouched
 */
strippedProps(): Object {
    let strippedProps: Object = {};

    Object.keys(this.props).forEach((key) => {
        let prop: any = this.props[key];

        if (typeof (prop) != 'function') {
            strippedProps[key] = prop;
        }
    })

    return strippedProps;
}
```

TS is angrily underlining, which I'm confused about, because `prop` here has specifically been declared as `any`.

[image]

Why is TS unsatisfied with the first error (warning) here? How could I refactor in order to keep the compiler happy and meet the need of generating this dynamic object?

Comment: Looks like a warning, not an error.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd still like to refactor to rid myself of all squiggles. Edited post to reflect this.

Comment: The message mentions adding an index signature. Try that. Also, if this is an IDE warning instead of a compiler warning, it may even be nonsensical. Try restarting your IDE and see if it persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index signature is missing on `this.props`' type.

---

> **[Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)**
>
> Similarly to how we can use interfaces to describe function types, we can also describe types that we can “index into” like a[10], or ageMap["daniel"]. Indexable types have an index signature that describes the types we can use to index into the object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing. Let’s take an example:

To fix it, you'd need to tell Typescript that `this.props`' object type has strings as keys:

```
interface QuestionViewProps { 
   ... your definition,
   [key: string]: myType,
}
```

---

Second options is to just suppress the warning via  ["suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html).

---

Third options is to cast to , which wouldn't be type-safe anymore:

```
 let prop: any = (<any>this.props)[key];
```

Comment: Thanks much. Still wrapping my head around how type indexing specifications are supposed to work, but I typed some things, my squiggly lines disappeared, and I am happy.